# Command on TreeViewItem item click, VSCode Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, treeview, vscode-extensions, treeviewitem

Context: a question related to building a clickable edit button on any item of a TreeView.

How can I call a callback function when the edit button in front of a  TreeViewItem is clicked?

Image of the edit button:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view#view-actions

I noticed the `command` property on the TreeItem instance and went through the docs but couldn't understand how to call a callback function with the command.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Docs:  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#TreeItem

```
"view/item/context": [
    {
        "command": "issuesList.deleteEntry",
        "when": "view == issuesList && viewItem == dependency",
        "group": "inline"
    },
    {
        "command": "issuesList.viewInVisualizer",
        "when": "view == issuesList && viewItem == dependency"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Better later than never :)

## Implement Updateable, Interactive `vscode.TreeView`

1. Contribute `TreeView` Update Command
2. Contribute `View` Object
3. Contribute `View` Update Button
4. Create & Register the `TreeView` class
5. Activate

### Contribute `TreeView` Update Command

Add `command` contribution to `package.json`

```json
{
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "Update-TreeView",
                "category": "Custom",
                "title": "Actively updates the tree view",
                "icon": "$(extensions-refresh)"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

### Contribute `View` Object

Add `view` contribution to `package.json`

```json
{
    "contributes": {
        "views": {
            "explorer": [
                {
                    "id": "customView",
                    "name": "Custom View"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Contribute `View` Update Button

Add button contribution for `customView` to `package.json`. Please note that we assigned the update command we have contribute earlier.

```json
{
    "contributes": {
        "menus": {
            "view/title": [
                {
                    "command": "Update-TreeView",
                    "when": "view == customView",
                    "group": "navigation"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Create & Register the `TreeView` class

#### Code Breakdown

1. `refresh` - fires when the `refresh` button is clicked on the view. We achieved that by registering the update command and fire the update event when invoking it.
2. `getChildren` - this is the logic by which you will build your tree.
3. `register` - a wrapper method for registering the tree provider and the update command.
4. `withProgress` - will show a progress bar while your tree is loaded/updated.
5. `TreeItem` - [a class for creating the tree items](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view).

> Important!
>
> Please check the events under `register` method. They will fire when you perform actions on your tree. In order to get the `TreeItem(s)` on which the action was preformed, call `e.selection` or `e.element`.

Create a new file `custom-tree.ts` and paste the following code inside

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export class CustomTreeDataProvider implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<TreeItem> {
    private _onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.EventEmitter<TreeItem | undefined | null | void> = new vscode.EventEmitter<TreeItem | undefined | null | void>();
    readonly onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.Event<TreeItem | undefined | null | void> = this._onDidChangeTreeData.event;

    refresh(): void {
        this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire();
    }

    getTreeItem(element: TreeItem): vscode.TreeItem | Thenable<vscode.TreeItem> {
        return element;
    }

    getChildren(element?: TreeItem | undefined): vscode.ProviderResult<TreeItem[]> {
        return vscode.window.withProgress({ location: { viewId: "customView" } }, () => {
            return new Promise<TreeItem[]>((resolve) => {
                let file = new TreeItem('file.txt', vscode.ThemeIcon.File, undefined);
                let folder = new TreeItem('Parent', vscode.ThemeIcon.Folder, [file]);

                resolve([folder]);
            });
        });
    }

    public register(context: vscode.ExtensionContext): any {
        // setup
        const options = {
            treeDataProvider: this,
            showCollapseAll: true
        };

        // build
        vscode.window.registerTreeDataProvider('customView', this);
        vscode.commands.registerCommand('Update-TreeView', () => {
            this.refresh();
        });

        // create
        const tree = vscode.window.createTreeView('customView', options);
        
        // setup: events
        tree.onDidChangeSelection(e => {
            console.log(e); // breakpoint here for debug
        });
        tree.onDidCollapseElement(e => {
            console.log(e); // breakpoint here for debug
        });
        tree.onDidChangeVisibility(e => {
            console.log(e); // breakpoint here for debug
        });
        tree.onDidExpandElement(e => {
            console.log(e); // breakpoint here for debug
        });

        // subscribe
        context.subscriptions.push(tree);
    }
}

class TreeItem extends vscode.TreeItem {
    children: TreeItem[] | undefined;
    command?: vscode.Command | undefined;

    constructor(
        label: string,
        iconPath?: string | vscode.Uri | { light: string | vscode.Uri; dark: string | vscode.Uri } | vscode.ThemeIcon,
        children?: TreeItem[] | undefined,
        command?: vscode.Command) {

        super(
            label,
            children === undefined
                ? vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None
                : vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.Collapsed);
        this.command = command;
        this.iconPath = iconPath;
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

### Activate

Add the following code to your `activate` method under `extension.ts`.

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import { CustomTreeDataProvider } from './custom-tree';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  new CustomTreeDataProvider().register(context);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    const tree = vscode.window.createTreeView('myview', {treeDataProvider: dataProvider, showCollapseAll: true });
    tree.onDidChangeSelection( e => click(e.selection));
```

Comment: Hi @wr_alan, thank you for answering this question, may I also recommend that providing an explanation can further improve your answer.

Comment: The question wanted to run a command on the inline icon selection, not the TreeViewItem itself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you should bind a function to the command by `vscode.commands.registerCommand` API. 
The code looks like

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    // other code
    vscode.commands.registerCommand('issuesList.deleteEntry', (node: Dependency) => node.deleteEntry());
    vscode.commands.registerCommand('issuesList.viewInVisualizer', (node: Dependency) => viewInVisualizer(node));
}
```

More detailed usage can be found at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#commands, and also a full example of TreeView at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/tree-view-sample